# Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at ..... Wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

Tags: backup, ubuntu-mate, source-code, avconv

I tried twice to write an .iso to a pendrive using BelenaEtcher.

```
Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/andy/Rescuezilla:

Wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Same message when using Mkusb.

I used Gparted and reformatted it twice.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to try and mount the partitions on the Rescuezilla live USB stick that you have just created.

Assuming balenaEtcher validated the flashed USB stick without any errors you can simply reboot your computer and boot from. You may need to press F8, F12 or a similar button  to enter the USB boot menu.

Indeed, as I [wrote](https://sourceforge.net/p/rescuezilla/discussion/support/thread/bf00bf3ca6/#d74a) on the Rescuezilla support forum:

> Of the 3 partitions exposed in the GPT partition table, only the EFI System Partition appears to be correctly exposed. I'm not sure why that is, but it definitely does not matter: the ESP is all that matters during EFI boot. Regardless of this, the Rescuezilla roadmap calls for getting rid of ISO9660 and move to partitioning structure with persistence ([task #8](https://github.com/rescuezilla/rescuezilla/issues/8)), so there's no point trying to expose the other two partitions on GPT.

It is strange that your operating system is trying to access the /dev/sdc1 partition. Regardless, your Rescuezilla USB stick created by balenaEtcher is ready to boot from.

Let me know in a comment below if you have any issues.

Comment: When I boot from it, there is a blinking cursor. @shasheene

Comment: So you are seeing the Rescuezilla [boot menu](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rescuezilla/rescuezilla.github.io/master/media/screenshots/1.png)?

What are the specifications of you computer? Is it a Dell, HP, etc? How old is it?

Comment: I see no boot menu. Model name:            AMD A8-7600 Radeon R7, 10 Computer Cores 4C+6G
CPU max MHz:           3100 MHz

Comment: When your computer starts up, do you press "F12" and see a list of attached hard drives? Is there two options describing the Rescuezilla pendrive as maybe "UEFI USB" and "Legacy USB"?

Comment: No.  I also do not have a Windows computer. @shasheene

Comment: I recommend shutting down your computer completely. Then remove and re-insert your USB stick. Then switch your computer back on and press a key like F2, F8 or F12 (the exact key depends on your computer). There should be a list of boot devices displayed. Hopefully there is an entry that refers to your Rescuezilla pendrive. By the way, did you write Rescuezilla 64-bit to your pendrive (rather than 32-bit)? A lot of modern computers have "legacy boot" disabled by default, the easiest solution is to boot using the 64-bit version of Rescuezilla which fully supports "UEFI".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110683/discussion-between-shasheene-and-fixit7).

Comment: @fixit7, please respond in the AskUbuntu chat linked above for further assistance